# How to store the result of join query in single variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test12 
     @varwi_name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @newbalance nvarchar(400)

    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            @newbalance = (SELECT 
                               (CAST(a.currentBal as INT) * CAST( b.monthlyInterestRate AS INT)) / 100  
                           FROM 
                               USR_0_CLOS_TransDet_TXN a, USR_0_CLOS_LoanReg_TXN b ON a.wi_name = b.wi_name)
       WHERE 
           wi_name = @varwi_name 
END
GO
```

I am getting ERROR

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'. Severity 15 Test12

Comment: Your variable is called `@newbalance` (which sounds like a **numeric** value) and the calculation returns a **numerical** value - yet it's declared as `nvarchar(400)` - doesn't seem to make any sense.... always use the **most appropriate** datatype - if it looks like a number, smells like a number, quacks like a number - it's a **NUMBER** and then you should **store is AS A NUMBER!** (not as a string)

Answer (score 1):

- You need the JOIN keyword for an ON clause
- Wrong placement of ( and )
- An extra BEGIN

As it should look:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test12
    @varwi_name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @newbalance nvarchar(400);

    SELECT
        @newbalance = (
                       SELECT
                        (CAST(a.currentBal AS int) * CAST(b.monthlyInterestRate AS int)) / 100
                       FROM
                        USR_0_CLOS_TransDet_TXN a
                        JOIN USR_0_CLOS_LoanReg_TXN b ON a.wi_name = b.wi_name
                       WHERE
                        wi_name = @varwi_name
                      );

END;
GO
```

Comment: Also: why have two `SELECT`? You could use `SELECT @newbalance = CAST.......` and save yourself the second `SELECT`.

Comment: @marc_s: `SELECT @newbalance = CAST...` will deal with multiple rows. The double SELECT will throw an error if there are. Are multiple rows exepcted?